# Show more / Show less two lists

Tags: jquery, css

I have two lists and a show more/show less button. Upon clicking on the button, my second list gets added to my first list. However the elements of the first list are already in the second and are rearranged differently.

I thought I could hide the elements of the first list and show only the second list. The problem is that when I click on the show less button my first list disappears.

I need help with jQuery so I can still show the first list when I click on show less and hide the second. I implemented the toggle only with CSS, no Javascript.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks

```js
$('#showmore').click(function() {
  $('#mylist li').hide();
});
```

```css
ul.check {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

ul.check li {
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 243px;
  background-image: url('../images/check.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 19px 6px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: LatoWebBold;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.readmore {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.readmore label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: LatoWebBlack;
  color: #282828;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: top .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
}

.readmore label:before,
.readmore label:after {
  text-align: center;
}

.readmore label:before {
  content: 'Show More';
  margin-right: 20px;
  left: 10px;
}

.readmore label:after {
  content: url('../images/arrow-down.png');
  -webkit-animation: sudo .85s linear infinite alternate;
  animation: sudo .85s linear infinite alternate;
}

input[type="checkbox"]~ul,
input[type="checkbox"]~a {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .80s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul,
[type="checkbox"]:checked~a {
  max-height: 800px;
}

.readmore [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  top: 100%;
}

.readmore [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: 'Show less';
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.readmore [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: url('../images/arrow-up.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="check" id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="readmore" id="showmore">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check_id">
  <label for="check_id"></label>
  <ul class="check" id="extra">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your checkbox gets checked when you click on `show more` is that required behaviour ?